# converting less to css goes wrong because of variables

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, gruntjs, phpstorm, byte-order-mark

I tried to use bootstrap with bower and grunt to create a good css for my Laravel project and everything works fine until I try to use the command

```
grunt less
```

In my Terminal it says

> NameError: variable @font-family-base is undefined in bower_components/bootstrap/less/scaffolding.less on line 28, column 16

and of course this happens for all the variables in the bootstrap directory. I have read people having problems with this before occurred by the UTF8 structure with BOM but in my editor ( PHPSTORM ) when I right-click on the bootstrap folder and click on remove BOM it doesn't help.

What else can I do to make this work?

p.s. I have used [this](http://blog.elenakolevska.com/using-grunt-with-laravel-and-bootstrap/) tutorial to create the structure

Answer (score 5):

Following the tutorial you've mentioned, you're importing

@import "variables.less";

in the base.less file. Try changing that to

@import "../../../bower_components/bootstrap/less/variables.less";

and hopefully it'll work.